# Using Pandas in Python to Join Multiple Files Based on Date

Tags: python, date, csv, join, pandas

I have csv files that I need to join together based upon date but the dates in each file are not the same (i.e. some files start on 1/1/1991 and other in 1998).  I have a basic start to the code (see below) but I am not sure where to go from here.  Any tips are appreciated.  Below please find a sample of the different csv I am trying to join.

```
import os, pandas as pd, glob
directory = r'C:\data\Monthly_Data'
files = os.listdir(directory)
print(files)
all_data =pd.DataFrame()
for f in glob.glob(directory):
    df=pd.read_csv(f)
    all_data=all_data.append(df,ignore_index=True)
all_data.describe()
```

File 1

```
DateTime    F1_cfs  F2_cfs  F3_cfs  F4_cfs  F5_cfs  F6_cfs  F7_cfs
3/31/1991   0.860702028 1.167239264 0   0   0   0   0
4/30/1991   2.116930556 2.463493056 3.316688418             
5/31/1991   4.056572581 4.544307796 5.562668011             
6/30/1991   1.587513889 2.348215278 2.611659722             
7/31/1991   0.55328629  1.089637097 1.132043011             
8/31/1991   0.29702957  0.54186828  0.585073925             2.624375
9/30/1991   0.237083333 0.323902778 0.362583333 0.925563094 1.157786606 2.68722973  2.104090278
```

File 2

```
DateTime    F1_mg-P_L   F2_mg-P_L   F3_mg-P_L   F4_mg-P_L   F5_mg-P_L   F6_mg-P_L   F7_mg-P_L
6/1/1992    0.05    0.05    0.06    0.04    0.03    0.18    0.08
7/1/1992    0.03    0.05    0.04    0.03    0.04    0.05    0.09
8/1/1992    0.02    0.03    0.02    0.02    0.02    0.02    0.02
```

File 3

```
DateTime    F1_TSS_mgL  F1_TVS_mgL  F2_TSS_mgL  F2_TVS_mgL  F3_TSS_mgL  F3_TVS_mgL  F4_TSS_mgL  F4_TVS_mgL  F5_TSS_mgL  F5_TVS_mgL  F6_TSS_mgL  F6_TVS_mgL  F7_TSS_mgL  F7_TVS_mgL
4/30/1991   10  7.285714286 8.5 6.083333333 3.7 3.1                             
5/31/1991   5.042553191 3.723404255 6.8 6.3 3.769230769 2.980769231                             
6/30/1991           5   5   1   1                               
7/31/1991                                                       
8/31/1991                                                       
9/30/1991   5.75    3.75    6.75    4.75    9.666666667 6.333333333 8.666666667 5   12  7.666666667 8   5.5 9   6.75
10/31/1991  14.33333333 9   14  10.66666667 16.25   11  12.75   9.25    10.25   7.25    29.33333333 18.33333333 13.66666667 9
11/30/1991  2.2 1.933333333 2   1.88    0   0   4.208333333 3.708333333 10.15151515 7.909090909 9.5 6.785714286 4.612903226 3.580645161
```

Comment: I am getting the following error:

IOError:  Initializing from file failed

Comment: if you want to append your data vertically (append rows) then you either have to normalize your column names or to skip header row in `read_csv(header=None)`. If you want to append your data horizontally (add columns) you have to specify `axis=1` in `append()`

Comment: Can you show me what it would look like to have axis=1 in append()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't read the csv files correctly.

1) You need to comment out the following lines because you never use it later in your code.

```
   files = os.listdir(directory)
   print(files)
```

2) `glob.glob(directory)` didnt return any match files.  glob.glob() takes **pattern** as argument, for example: `'C:\data\Monthly_Data\File*.csv'`, unfortunately you put a directory as a pattern, and no files are found

`for f in glob.glob(directory):`

I modified the above 2 parts and `print all_data`, the file contents display on my console